# Struts2 - How to escape values while filling the options of a select box

Tags: struts2, struts

I have the following code :

```
<s:select name="user.primaryGroup.id" list="#groupListAction.groups" listKey="id" listValue="name"
  headerKey="" headerValue="Please select" id="addUser-primaryGroup" />
```

The problem is that the option text will have unescaped HTML like `<b>Name</b>`. This will cause the options to be displayed in bold. How can I prevent this ? Only the `<s:property/>` tag seems to escape html.

Answer (score 0):

That's true.. According to documentation, only [property tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/property.html) has parameter `escape` which is by default set to true. [Select tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/select.html) has no such parameter, so I am afraid you have to escape HTML server side... You can use JSoup or similar library for HTML manipulation...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach instead: html select with struts iterator `<s:iterator`>

```
<select id="xxx" size="1" name="xxx">
   <option value=""> <s:text name="page.search.emptyOption" /></option>          
   <s:iterator value="xxx">                     
      <s:if test="%{key.indexOf('|') == -1}">
         <option value="">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</option>
      </s:if>
   </s:iterator>
</select>
```

This will allow you to control the situation with `<s:property>` tag and escape it.